# video not found or access denied when playing .flv file

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, flash, swfobject

i have used .flv file my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playerFlv = new SWFObject(path + 'player.swf', "Player", "500", "350", "9");
                playerFlv.addVariable('allowfullscreen', 'true');
                playerFlv.addVariable("allowscriptaccess", "always");
                playerFlv.addVariable("enableJavascript", "true");              
                playerFlv.addVariable("image", path + Image);
                playerFlv.addVariable("file", path + 'VideoFile/' + video);
                playerFlv.write("playerview");
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the "file" var is getting put together right?  Is path guaranteed to have a trailing slash?

Comment: @keith.layne I dont under stand clearly.Plz explane.Thanks.

Comment: Try this: print out (or alert, or whatever your language allows) `path + 'VideoFile/' + video`.  See if it makes sense.  Also, if the file isn't found/access is denied there should be some record of how it failed in the server logs.

Comment: I think this should be like `path + '/VideoFile/' + video`, hope its one level below the images path

Comment: @V4Vendetta in 'path' it hold '/' at the end so that no problem with 'VideoFile/', any other idea, suggest plz

Comment: Like I said, look at the server logs to see what the actual failure is.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the .flv Extension to your Mime Types in IIS it should be: video/x-flv